# How to kill the process that contains a file that was opened using the default file handler?

Tags: java, windows

I want to open a document (PDF, WORD, TXT, etc) in a separate window and then be able to close it again programmatically at some point later.

I have tried using

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler MyFile.txt");
// delay
p.destroy();
```

but this doesn't seem to work. I saw somewhere that there is a bug in the Windows implementation (currently using Java 1.8).

So I tried Apache Commons Exec.

```
CommandLine cmdLine = CommandLine.parse("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler MyFile.txt");
DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
ExecuteWatchdog watchdog = new ExecuteWatchdog(ExecuteWatchdog.INFINITE_TIMEOUT);
executor.setWatchdog(watchdog);
DefaultExecuteResultHandler handler = new DefaultExecuteResultHandler();
executor.execute(cmdLine, handler);
System.out.println("Watching " + watchdog.isWatching());

Thread.sleep(2000);

System.out.println("Watching " + watchdog.isWatching());
        
watchdog.destroyProcess();

System.out.println("Killed " + watchdog.killedProcess());
```

The result is

```
Watching true
Watching false
Killed false
```

The document is opened but does not get closed. I assume that the file handler spawns a new process and ends. The new process containing the document is not reachable via the original process.

Right?

Is there another way to open and close the document?